# Need to change Python HTML Template Language

Tags: html, templates, flask, pycharm, jinja2

I'm working on a project in PyCharm that involves Python, Flask and Jinja code, but PyCharm isn't recognizing the Jinja code when I go to preview the html pages.  I've read that I need to change my Template Language to Jinja2 in PyCharm for it to work, but I believe it's only available for the professional version.
Is there a workaround of do I need to switch to another IDE? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest vscode, I couldn't manage to find it in the community edition of PyCharm either.

Comment: Ugh I was hoping to avoid switching IDE's but I guess I don't have a choice.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.  In order for the jinja code to be recognized I needed to run the python app containing Flask code in the command line:
`python application.py`

This will generated a url in the terminal and clicking on it opened up the html page in my browser.

Make sure that the following lines are at the bottom of your python code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```